# Github for Windows won't start

Tags: windows-7, installation, git, github, github-desktop

The error log generated after the installation when i try to open the application reads :

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.17929
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [1/13/2017 7:24:38 PM] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [1/13/2017 7:24:38 PM] System.UnauthorizedAccessException
        - Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore(UInt32 Flags, IntPtr hToken, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore..ctor(ComponentStoreType storeType, SubscriptionStore subStore)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore..ctor(String deployPath, String tempPath, ComponentStoreType storeType)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.get_CurrentUser()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

The OS is win7 32bit. What is wrong? Why won't Github start?

Comment: Have you tried opening the program in administrative mode?

Comment: @FoxMcloud5655 Yes I have. This is what happens.

Comment: Hmm...  Have you tried re-downloading the .application file and running that?

Comment: @FoxMcloud5655 Yes I have. Same problem reappears.

Comment: It might have something to do with the account you're registered under in GitHub, as the "Access Denied" is pointing to a web address, "http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application".